# pagefactory ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using page factory pattern, The Argument error showing me in there places

1. Here is My class Homepage:-

   ```
    require 'page-object/page_factory'
    class Homepage
    include PageObject
    include Configuration


    def initialize(browser)
       @browser = browser
     end

     def open
       goto("url")
     end

     def sign_in
    @browser.element(css: 'div.links-static ul li.account div#login_user_data a.account').click
    end

     def create_account
    @browser.element(css: 'div.ml_function.ml_function_arrowtoptoleft.padding_top_twenty.height_fifty input.ml_function_button_createaccountRegister').click
     end
   end
   ```
2. Given(/^I am on shopclues homepage$/) do
   visit(Homepage)
   end
3. Scenario: User needs to create a new account
   Given I am on shopclues homepage ----> Here it is showing the error
   When I click on sign in
   And I fill the user information
   And I click Create Account
   Then I should see the user details

Comment: Could you please update your question with the error you get? The error message and stack trace usually holds a lot of useful information about whats going wrong.

Most importantly it should show you if the error comes from your code, or from a dependency (for instance the page-object thing) or from how you're using the dependency.

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
./features/lib/pages/Homepage.rb:7:in `initialize'
./features/step_definitions/Homepage_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on shopclues homepage$/'
./features/Homepage.feature:9:in `Given I am on shopclues homepage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have re-defined the `initialize` method for the page object.

When you `include PageObject`, an [`initialize` method is already added](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object.rb#L78-L83):

```
def initialize(root, visit=false)
  initialize_accessors if respond_to?(:initialize_accessors)
  initialize_browser(root)
  goto if visit && respond_to?(:goto)
  initialize_page if respond_to?(:initialize_page)
end
```

Notice that the default method can accept up to 2 arguments. When using the `visit` method, your page object is initialized with 2 arguments. Given that you have re-defined your `initialize` method to only accept 1 argument, the exception occurs.

Unless you have a special reason for doing so, you should remove the custom `initialize` - ie the class should just be:

```
class Homepage
  include PageObject
  include Configuration

  def open
    goto("url")
  end

  def sign_in
    @browser.element(css: 'div.links-static ul li.account div#login_user_data a.account').click
  end

  def create_account
    @browser.element(css: 'div.ml_function.ml_function_arrowtoptoleft.padding_top_twenty.height_fifty input.ml_function_button_createaccountRegister').click
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin Ko, But Now I am getting this error. 
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:css=>"div.links-static ul li.account div#login_user_data a.account"}

Comment: That means the element does not exist. There are quite a few reasons why that will occur. Without access to the page you are working with, I cannot tell you exactly why the exception is occurring. All I can suggest is that you go through the list of possible causes - I have a [list on my blog](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/).

Comment: The browser is opened but the url is not displaying in search bar, in search bar it is  displaying the "data:,". I don't know why it is displaying the data:

Comment: Hi Justin Ko, do you have any idea about this error.

Comment: I assume you are using Chrome. "data:" is just the default that appears when the browser is opened. Have you actually told your browser to go somewhere? `visit(Homepage)` won't actually navigate anywhere as you have not specified the URL for the page object.

Comment: I found the mistake, I should not define the url in a separate method. Thanks Justin Ko